# dojo widget layout

Tags: layout, widget, dojo

Currently I am porting client side of my application from Active X to Dojo. This is first time Iam working with dojo. I have looked at Dojo layout documentation but I am not sure how can I use them for my purposes. The dialogs in my application are typically look like the attached image

[image: Dojo Dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to use dojo's layout widget, you can always use HTML and CSS to create you own layout. The layout widget can help you to layout different components in you page, but it also introduces runtime overhead.

From your picture, the only layout widget you should use is `dijit.layout.SplitContainer`. It seems that the dialog is consisted of two vertical parts. If the user is allowed to adjust the relative size of these two parts, use `dijit.layout.SplitContainer`. Otherwise, use plain HTML and CSS to layout the widget.

If you do want to use layout widget to simplify the layout, you can use `dijit.layout.BorderContainer` to layout different components. For example, you can put the buttons into the `bottom` region of the `BorderContainer` and put the edit box in the `center` region.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for answer. Problem is I am completely newbie to this web design stuff :-(. I will really appreciate if you could advice me on how to use HTML/CSS for layout. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: I recommend you to start from some CSS frameworks, e.g http://www.blueprintcss.org/ That will make the design much easier.

Comment: you may want to use a dijit.Dialog to provide the title bar, floating, and modal behavior.  Like Alex says, it's nice to keep the UI as light as possible.  The rest could be plain HTML+CSS, but BorderContainer may be useful, particularly if you want a moving splitter.  Beware, SplitContainer is deprecated; use BorderContainer instead.   The CSS "4 corners" trick can also be used to make your layout resize and expand without using layout widgets.  Using Dijit widgets for all the buttons, etc., would give you a consistent and themed look and feel, if that's what you're after.